# Problem with fillbetween pgfplots library and intersections

Tags: pgfplots, intersections, fillbetween

In this MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, landscape]{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
  intersections,
 }

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt, color=black, >=latex]
\begin{axis}[%
width=9cm,height=7cm, samples=250,
scale only axis,
axis lines = middle, hide y axis,
xmin=-2,xmax=3,xlabel={$r$}, 
ymin=0,ymax=0.5]

\coordinate (a) at (-1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);

\addplot[mark=none, line width=1pt, color=blue,domain=-2:3, name path=line 1] {(1/sqrt(2*pi))*e^-((x-1)^2/2)};

\addplot[mark=none, line width=1pt,color=red,domain=-2:3, name path=line 2] {(1/sqrt(2*pi))*e^-((x-2)^2/8)} ;

\draw[red, dashed, name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2,name=i, total=\t}] \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) -- ($(a)!(i-\s)!(b)$)} ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

there is a fatal error, but if you compose without fillbetween library, the output is okay. There is not any error with TL2017. I know the fillbetween library is not necessary for this code. Any help?

Comment: You can add the bug report here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/?source=navbar. The culprit commit seems to be https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/33425.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Dear Ulrike, could you take a look on this issue:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438131/tex-capacity-exceeded-after-miktex-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Comment on your question

Without checking if fixing [bug #139](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139/) really caused this issue as Ulrike stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437172/problem-with-fillbetween-pgfplots-library-and-intersections#comment1097138_437172), this issue was fixed in PGF (see my comment at the [bug report in the PGFPlots tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/206/#f5cf)).

### Fix for your problem

For your given example it is quite easy to make it work, also *with* the `fillbetween` library. Simply reduce the number of `samples`. 51 will be more than enough as can be seen in the following code. Especially when `smooth` is used as well. Than even 25 samples could be enough.

(Please note, that I made some other improvements to your code as well. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.)

```
% usded PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=0.5,
        xlabel={$r$},
        % (changed from `middle' to `left' so that also the 0 label is shown)
        axis lines=left,
        hide y axis,
        domain=-2:3,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % reduced number of samples to make it work
        samples=51,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % this is just to show that this number of samples is more than enough,
        % especially when combined with `smooth'
%        no markers,
        smooth,
    ]

        \addplot+ [name path=line 1] {1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-((x-1)^2/2))};
        \addplot+ [name path=line 2] {1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-((x-2)^2/8))};

        \draw [
            red,
            dashed,
            name intersections={
                of=line 1 and line 2,
                name=i,
                total=\t,
            },
        ] \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} {
            % (this is a bit simpler than your approach.
            %  there is no need for coordinates (a) and (b)
            %   and no need for the `calc' library)
            (i-\s) -- (i-\s |- 0,0)
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Dear Stefan: after your comment, I have been able to check the only change necessary is to add 'smooth' to my code. Your improvements are very useful and nice, thank you. I think the problem is solved, at least in this case.