# How to increase memory size for xelatex in MikTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, memory

I'd like to enlarge the memory size used by xelatex. In the MikTeX documentation it says:

> The name of the configuration file is that of the engine (e.g.,
>   miktex-pdftex) or format (e.g, miktex-pdflatex). You use the
>   --edit-config-file option of initexmf to edit the configuration file, e.g.:
>
> initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex

What shall I do in order to increase memory size used by xelatex?

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=xelatex
initexmf --edit-config-file=xetex
initexmf --edit-config-file=miktex-xetex
```

And which command do I have to run afterwards to apply the changes?

May I put the --admin option if I want to apply the changes to all system users?

Comment: I don't think you should need no enlarge the memory... Are you getting an error saying that there is not enough memory?

Comment: Yes, I described the problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438131/tex-capacity-exceeded-after-miktex-update?noredirect=1#comment1099699_438131)

Comment: BTW, a similar problem is described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload

Comment: Sorry, I asked because *usually* (which is not always), increasing memory does not solve the problem because TeX is stuck in a loop. Of course this is not you case :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your document uses really a lot of memory and for an unknown reason the default memory for xelatex is smaller then the one for pdflatex in miktex.

You can increase the memory with

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=xelatex
```

This will hopefully open xelatex.ini in your editor.

Then you can add either

```
 extra_mem_top = 2000000
```

This will work directly. Simply save the file.

Or add

```
 main_memory = 5000000
```

This will need a recreation of the format with (or with the console)

```
 initexmf --dump=xelatex
```

If you want to do it for all users use

```
 initexmf --admin --edit-config-file=xelatex
```

and

```
 initexmf --admin --dump=xelatex
```

But be aware that user settings and user formats can shadow settings and formats of the admin and so non-admin calls are perhaps needed too -- I can't test this as I don't have a multi user installation.

Comment: Thank you, @Ulrike. After After increasing the memory size with `extra_mem_top = 2000000` I get another error:

! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
\end@float ...loatpenalty <-\@Mii \penalty -\@Miv 
                                                  \@tempdima \prevdepth \vbo...
l.48 \end{figure}
                 
I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a
\shipout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time
increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient!

Comment: I had no problem with your example. But if in your real document you are really using so many floats (figure) it could be problematic. Insert \clearpage somewhere.

Comment: No, in my real document there are only 6 plots in one figure.

Comment: Ok, after setting `extra_mem_top = 2000000`in C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\xelatex.ini my original document compiles again :)
Thank you @Ulrike !!!!

Comment: You shouldn't change the original files. miktex can overwrite them at updates.

Comment: but that's the file which is opened when I type `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file=xelatex`
Should I then save the modified file to somewhere else?

Comment: Ah. sorry I read program files and not programData. this should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

For me the one thing that worked was to find the **installation directory** of MikTeX and change the parameters in the file `<install dir>\miktex\config\texmfapp.ini`. After doing that it worked like charm!