# Problems Changing default memory size [main memory size=5000000]

Tags: memory

I have a large project (a book) of c 450 pages in length. I am using TexShop on OSX with LaTeX to produce a PDF.

The project  builds on the first pass, but on the second pass when it is filling in the contents and cross references it fails with:

```
(/Users/Sean/PIC/BookLibraries/LUT.X/LUT1.asm)
(/Users/Sean/PIC/BookLibraries/LUT.X/LUT2.asm [281])
./subroutines.tex:130: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
<argument> ...p_box \vbox_unpack:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \kern \c_zero_dim 
l.130 }
       
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 102928 strings out of 479917
 2426234 string characters out of 5882726
 4999999 words of memory out of 5000000
 105338 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 755283 words of font info for 339 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 146i,20n,184p,2382b,2938s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
./subroutines.tex:130:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The location of failure is in a Listing but is not remotely unusual, there are many such in the book.

I have altered the   .../texlive/2020/texmf.cnf by adding

```
main_memory = 600000 % words of inimemory available; also applies to inimf&mp
main_memory.tex = 600000
main_memory.latex = 600000
main_memory.pdflatex = 600000
```

but as the error still reports a main memory size of [main memory size=5000000] at failure.

Are there are other parametrs I can vary?

Comment: First of all you should show some code, as this might stem from a badly programmed macro that ends up in the toc and is, say, expanded too early

Comment: Thanks, I could do so, but the specific question is why the error message insists the memory size is 5000000 when I have altered the memory size in what I think are the likely sections to 6000000. There is so much code that it is difficult to think of an MWE. A link to an earlier version of the pdf generated is here: http://www.stbarnabaschapel.net/book1.pdf

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438902/how-to-increase-memory-size-for-xelatex-in-miktex will helps you

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case at least and I ave simulated the anticipated final size of the book c 900 pages by duplicating Chapters. It may be of some help if others are genuinely running out of memory.

```
main_memory = 12000000
extra_mem_bot = 12000000
font_mem_size = 12000000
pool_size = 12000000
buf_size = 12000000
```

Comment: For completeness, and for the answer to be a helpful reference to others, it's important to mention the following: for the changes to come into effect at all, "[we] have to redump the .fmt file after changing main_memory" (quote from `textmf.cnf`). This is done by running `fmtutil`. The syntax under OSX has changed a bit over the years; currently (OSX 10.15) you can run `sudo fmtutil --sys --all` in the Terminal.

Comment: For those interested in understanding more regarding the difference between `sudo fmtutil --sys --all` and `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` for example, `tug.org` has a concise description of, and the differences between `fmtutil`, `fmtutil-sys`, and `fmtutil-user` at https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/fmtutil.html?ixtgbu47ztirvlil3jr3ebjtxy=hbr2vntatrg3tz75gtjgy53uny.