# Help on TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000] (using XeLaTeX and LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf)

Tags: memory, texcapacity

In my book project, I have 10 chapter and more than 300 images, and all are color (`CMYK`) images, if I run each chapter individiually everything working fine, but if I run all chapters through a main file, it produced the error:

```
\__morewrites_tex_immediate:w \__morewrites_tex_write:w \g__morewrites_iow \ETC
.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\g__morewrites_iow_19_tl ...__morewrites_iow \ETC.
```

I need to use `LaTeX-dvips-PS2PDF` or `XeLaTeX` and I'm using `MikTeX2.9` on `Windows10` system, is there any way to increase the memory? Please advise.

`MWE` is

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{amssymb}

\documentclass[%
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=true, 
    open=any, 
    chapterentrydots=true, 
    numbers=noenddot 
]{kaobook}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Bibliography

%\usepackage{showframe}
\def\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.125pt}

\begin{document}

\include{Ch01}
\include{Ch02}
...
\include{Ch10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: increasing memory will probably not help. This looks like a loop. You will have to produce a real complete minimal example that can be used for a test. Or try to prevent the morewrites package from loading with `\PreventPackageFromLoading{morewrites}`

Comment: Please try with  one of `Ulrike`'s reply https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438902/how-to-increase-memory-size-for-xelatex-in-miktex hope this may helps you

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Your suggestion which was mentioned by MadyYuvi working fine for me, kindly confirm OK to follow the same?