# How to increase memory in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my a document (lots of very long tables):

```
./Chap-Syb.tex:977: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory
 size=5000000].
```

I've tried to supply `-extra-mem-bot= 50000000` to the LaTeX process *Preferences > Engine* but this didn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: (1) that has nothing to do with TeXShop. (2) What exactly are you doing? In many of these cases this is caused by user error. So I'd explore that before changing the memory size. (3) Lualatex uses dynamic memory so you can try that instead.

Comment: TeXShop triggers pdflatex so I should be able to pass a command to that process, no?

Comment: Nothing related with `TeXShop` this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438902/how-to-increase-memory-size-for-xelatex-in-miktex will helps you

Comment: From that answer, you replace `xelatex` to `pdflatex` and then try

Comment: But as far as I can see there is no commandline option to increase the memory size. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @daleif Sorry, do you ask me or the `OP`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi the op, sorry for the confusion

Comment: if you use `longtable` then the memory doesn't really increase as the table gets longer (as long as it has enough to hold one page) check you are not looping and that you really need more memory. You have not said what tex system (miktex or texlive) or what engine (pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex) you are using. You could try using lualatex which does dynamic memory allocation in most cases.

Comment: @daleif there is a generic commandline option to set a texmf.cnf parameter  `-cnf-line=STRING        parse STRING as a configuration file line` in texlive at least (not sure about miktex)